# Convert an UCS-2 string to UTF-8 using ICU

Tags: c, utf-8, utf-16, icu

Can you please help me convert an UCS-2 string to UTF-8 using ICU ?

I'm using the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
UConverter *conv;
char buf[1000];
int32_t buflen;

conv = ucnv_open("utf-8", &status);

if (U_FAILURE(status))
{
    LOG(L_ERROR, "%s: Can not open the ICU converter\n", __FUNCTION__);
}
else
{
    buflen = ucnv_fromUChars(conv, buf, sizeof(buf), (UChar*)sms->message.s, sms->message.len, &status);

    if (U_FAILURE(status))
    {
        LOG(L_ERROR, "%s: Error in conversion: %s\n", __FUNCTION__, u_errorName(status));
    }
}

LOG(L_DEBUG, "%s: Conversion made ...\n", __FUNCTION__);
hexdump(sms->message.s, sms->message.len);
hexdump(buf, buflen);
```

sms->message is a struct:

```
typedef struct str
{
    char *s;
    int len;
} str_t;
```

The hexdump prints the following (input text: "aaaa"):

```
[DEBUG] add_recv_sms_to_db: Conversion made ...
000000: 00 61 00 61 00 61 00 61                          .a.a.a.a
000000: e6 84 80 e6 84 80 e6 84 80 e6 84 80 00 00 49 00  ..............I.
```

Comment: You may also want to tag your question with `c` or `c++` or whatever this is to make sure the right people see it.

Answer (score 0):

`e6 84 80` is UTF-8 for [U+6100](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/6100/index.htm), a CJK unified ideograph. It looks like `sms->message.s` is in little endian while your system is interpreting it in big endian (so `0x0061` becomes `0x6100`).

You can use the `UCNV_UTF16_LittleEndian` converter, or just perform a byte swap before passing `sms->message.s` to ICU.

Comment: You're right, i needed a byte swap.
I'm using this function:

`short swap_bytes_16(short input)`
`{`
   `return (input>>8) | (input<<8);`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is linked to the endiannes issue spotted by @ecatmur but you are casting `sms->message.s` which is a `char*` into a `Uchar*`

Looking at [here](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/umachine_8h.html#a6bb9fad572d65b305324ef288165e2ac):

> Define UChar to be UCHAR_TYPE, if that is #defined (for example, to char16_t), or wchar_t if that is 16 bits wide; always assumed to be unsigned.
>
> If neither is available, then define UChar to be uint16_t.
>
> This makes the definition of UChar platform-dependent but allows direct string type compatibility with platforms with 16-bit wchar_t types.

Are you sure this cast is safe ?